# How do we request publish_actions in Facebook for a private app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, publish-actions

My Android app connects to a Wifi camera, grabs a picture and asks the user his Facebook login to post the picture on his wall. Publishing works very well with my developper account ; however, to make it usable by any user, I need to get the `publish_actions` authorization for my app.

I've submitted a request to the Facebook team, enclosing a video of the picture posting workflow, the privacy policy, a 1024x1024 app icon, and so on... but the team replied by with a deny for the following reason: they could not reproduce the publishing steps.

This is absolutely normal since:

- The app is private, not published on any store
- The app requires specific Wifi camera (with specific brand and model) to work properly and publish a picture on Facebook so even providing the private APK to Facebook wouldn't solve the problem.

They tell to fix the issue and make an other attempt. How do I fix this issue, though?

Comment: Have you properly and unmistakably alerted them to the fact that they can’t test this app themselves due to those reasons in your review instructions? Make that absolutely clear, and submit again.

Comment: Yes, in a comment, I'll reinforce this information, resubmit, and update my question here.